# Как сделать так, чтобы текст в блоке div перемещался во вторую колонку

Tags: css3, html5

Есть блок `div`:

```css
.fullmenu {
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 402px;
  background: #002458;
  padding: 4px;
}

.block1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #cccccc;
  float: left;
}

.secondlvl li {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.thirdlvl li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullmenu">
  <div class="block1">

    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы как только у блока `block1` кончалась высота, списки продолжались в этом же блоке во второй колонке, потом в третьей, и так, пока не кончится ширина. Но за высоту никогда не залазить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
.block1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 450px;
}

.secondlv1 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullmenu">
  <div class="block1">

    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondlvl">
      <p><a href="">Базовый хирургческий инструмент</a></p>
      <li>
        <ul class="thirdlvl">
          <p class="arrow">▼</p>
          <a href="">Артериальные зажимы</a>
          <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3.1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а без flexbox это никак нельзя?

Comment: можно display:inline-block; только переносы сами сработают - но надо будет ограничить родительский блок по ширине